# How do I send a HTTP/2 POST request in PHP

Tags: php, curl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, http2

I found a similar question at [Sending HTTP/2 POST request in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458223/how-do-i-send-a-http-2-post-request-in-ruby)
But I want to update my server with PHP

The new Apple push notification HTTP/2 based API described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html

Anyone with HTTP/2 experience help me with making a request as a client in PHP.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The CURL extension for PHP >= 5.5.24 has support for HTTP/2. (since [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/1badfd8171119ef70a5d088068b9de88ba668f73))

You also need a libcurl installed — the underlying library that the curl functions use — with HTTP/2 support enabled. That means a libcurl newer than 7.38.0 but really, the newer the better. Libcurl has to have been built with HTTP/2 support explicitly enabled, using the `--with-nghttp2` flag at compile time.

Just use curl as you'd normally use it, and set the [`CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html) option to use HTTP/2 by passing in `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0`. Then you'll get the request upgraded to version 2 *if* the client and server both support it.

Prior to PHP 5.5.24, if libcurl has been built with HTTP/2 support, you can pass in the int value of `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0` explicitly as PHP will still pass it through to libcurl. Currently, it has a value of `3` — this should not change, but *could*.

```php
if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
    define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
```

Comment: I tried installing both versions 5.6.21 and 7.0.6 of XAMPP on both Mac and Linux, but I'm always getting this error: `HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes ...`. Do you know how I can solve this? I'm able to send push notifications from the command line, but in PHP it doesn't work.

Comment: I would like to understand if push notifications with HTTP/2 and curl 7.38.0 will work in shared hosting environment? Previously shared hosting providers would block ports 2195 and 2196 due to security reasons hence push notification using TCP socket would not be possible.

Comment: @raj: that's a totally separate question, not suitable for a comment to an answer...

Comment: This also requires openSSL 1.0.2 which is not available via yum update on centOS 6, even though 1.0.1 is now 5 years old and counting.

Answer (score 6):

Having PHP >= 5.5.24 is not enough to make a HTTP/2 request with curl, even if CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0 is defined. You will get an error message like the following if you try to make a request to APNS (Apple Push Notification Service):

```
?@@?HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 504f5354202f332f6465766963652f616538666562613534
```

Since curl is a [binding](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/) for libcurl, you must also have curl with http/2 enabled.

For a sample code, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684099/new-apns-provider-api-and-php/34831873#34831873) to a similar question here on SO

For install procedure, you can follow this [tutorial](https://serversforhackers.com/video/curl-with-http2-support)

Comment: thanks! This worked. Though I checked the request headers using `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` and it shows `HTTP/1.1`. But it's working now, where it wasn't working before.

Comment: I have PHP 5.6, curl 7.54 (with HTTP2 support) and OpenSSL 1.0.1 yet `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0` is still undefined, any ideas why?
Apple returns an `Unexpected HTTP/1.x request` error message when attempting to connect.

Comment: @Andrew check that your curl OpenSSL version is above 1.0.1. I ended up needlessly recompiling my PHP version to finally discover that Apple APNs require a never version of TLS.

Comment: @andreszs I had the same problem until I simply restarted apache with `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 2):

At the current moment there is no direct `HTTP/2` support in PHP.

There is an **idea** to add such a support in the future direct to PHP:
https://wiki.php.net/ideas/php6#http2_support

The 3rd Party library Guzzle https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle supports HTTP/2, if the correct php and curl version are installed:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$client->get('https://http2.akamai.com/demo/tile-0.png', [
    'version' => 2.0,
    'debug' => true,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Apache](https://github.com/norbertmocsnik/php-5.6-apache-http2) and [CLI](https://github.com/norbertmocsnik/php-5.6-cli-http2) PHP Docker images I built for this purpose that add HTTP/2 support to the official PHP 5.6 docker library. This gets rid of any `HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt` errors.

Once you have the right environment, having tried several JWS/JWT libraries for PHP I only found [Spomky-Labs/jose](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose) to work perfectly with APNs.