# Make HTTP/2 request with PHP

Tags: php, curl, http2

Is there a way to force PHP to make a HTTP2 connection to another server just to see if that server supports it?

I've tried:

```
$options = stream_context_create(array(
               'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'timeout' => 5,
                    'protocol_version' => 1.1
                )
              ));
$res = file_get_contents($url, false, $options);
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

And tried:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 3);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
curl_close($ch);
```

But both ways give me a HTTP1.1 response if I use the following URL `https://www.google.com/#q=apache+2.5+http%2F2`

I'm sending the request from a HTTP/2 + SSL enabled domain. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of php are you using ? take a look here https://blog.cloudflare.com/tools-for-debugging-testing-and-using-http-2/

Comment: have you tried: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606801/how-do-i-send-a-http-2-post-request-in-php)

Comment: is your libcurl version built to support HTTP/2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, cURL is the only transfer method in PHP that supports HTTP 2.0.

You'll first need to test that your version of cURL can support it, and then set the correct version header:

```
if (
    defined("CURL_VERSION_HTTP2") &&
    (curl_version()["features"] & CURL_VERSION_HTTP2) !== 0
) {
    $url = "https://www.google.com/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL            =>$url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         =>true,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY         =>true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   =>CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($response !== false && str_starts_with($response, "HTTP/2")) {
        echo "HTTP/2 support!";
    } elseif ($response !== false) {
        echo "No HTTP/2 support on server.";
    } else {
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    echo "No HTTP/2 support on client.";
}
```

Comment: Depending on your platform/versions, it might need a few tweaks to get it done, as it did with me: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45110402/1005334]

Comment: Any ideas why CLI requests such as `curl --http2 -I https://nghttp2.org/` do work in HTTP2 mode but when switching to PHP, they are sent as HTTP 1.1 instead? I've tested your code and it still doesn't work in HTTP2 mode. I have PHP 5.6 and curl 7.54.

Comment: @Andrew Because the curl you’re using in the command line isn’t necessarily the same on that’s complied into PHP for its curl support.

Comment: The minor version (2.0) was dropped from HTTP2.  https://http2.github.io/faq/#is-it-http20-or-http2

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ryre. This code will, of course, continue to work with older servers still sending "2.0" as well.

Comment: The first line of this answer doesn't work.  Should be `if ( !empty(@constant('CURL_VERSION_HTTP2')) ) {`

Comment: @FoulFoot 1) the constant can be defined without the feature being available 2) don't use the error suppression operator, it's an ugly hack; use `defined()` to test 3) if you're running a PHP version so old that the constant isn't defined, you've got bigger problems than an undefined constant notice.

Comment: I would suggest trying your code out on a client server that does not support HTTP/2, and you will see that it does not work.  My correction does work.  This isn't a function of old PHP, but old Apache -- which is much more common than Apache which supports HTTP/2.

Comment: Well, don't know what to tell you.  Running this on my server with PHP 7.3 results in this: `Warning: Use of undefined constant CURL_VERSION_HTTP2 - assumed 'CURL_VERSION_HTTP2' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/server/public_html/test.php on line 10

Warning: Use of undefined constant CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0 - assumed 'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/server/public_html/test.php on line 18
No HTTP/2 support on server.`  At the very least, indicating that it didn't trigger the "else" clause.

Comment: @FoulFoot ok when in doubt, go to the source. It looks like I was wrong about the constant always being defined; [there is a version check](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4.13/ext/curl/interface.c#L499) on the library done before the constant is defined. You can check your server's version with `echo curl_version()['version'];`. I've updated the code to check for the constant. Thanks for pushing back!