# cURL unable to rewind body with APN

Tags: php, curl, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send a message to an iOS device using APN, but keep getting this message:

*cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)*

I've tried disabling/enabling https, but doesn't seem to make any difference. The headers look to be exactly the same as their [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1), but doesn't want to make any difference. Anyone have any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
$payload = [
        "aps" =>  [
            "alert" => "Message received from Bob"
        ]
    ];

$client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request(
        'POST',
        'https://api.development.push.apple.com:443',
        [
            'body' => \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($payload),
            'headers' =>
                [
                    'Authorization' => "Bearer: $token",
                    ':method' => 'POST',
                    ':scheme' => 'https',
                    ':path' => "/3/device/$deviceId",
                    'apns-expiration' => 0,
                    'apns-priority' => 10
                ],
            'debug' => true,
        ]
    );
```

Curl version info:

```
array (size=9)
  'version_number' => int 470272
  'age' => int 3
  'features' => int 573981
  'ssl_version_number' => int 0
  'version' => string '7.45.0' (length=6)
  'host' => string 'x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0' (length=25)
  'ssl_version' => string 'OpenSSL/1.0.1p' (length=14)
  'libz_version' => string '1.2.8' (length=5)
  'protocols' => 
    array (size=20)
      0 => string 'dict' (length=4)
      1 => string 'file' (length=4)
      2 => string 'ftp' (length=3)
      3 => string 'ftps' (length=4)
      4 => string 'gopher' (length=6)
      5 => string 'http' (length=4)
      6 => string 'https' (length=5)
      7 => string 'imap' (length=4)
      8 => string 'imaps' (length=5)
      9 => string 'ldap' (length=4)
      10 => string 'ldaps' (length=5)
      11 => string 'pop3' (length=4)
      12 => string 'pop3s' (length=5)
      13 => string 'rtsp' (length=4)
      14 => string 'smb' (length=3)
      15 => string 'smbs' (length=4)
      16 => string 'smtp' (length=4)
      17 => string 'smtps' (length=5)
      18 => string 'telnet' (length=6)
      19 => string 'tftp' (length=4)
```

Comment: The Client class. What is the FQN?

Comment: Coming from Laravel, so GuzzleHttp\Client;

Comment: I also need to see you `var_dump(curl_version());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a HTTP/2 POST request in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606801/how-do-i-send-a-http-2-post-request-in-php)

Comment: Having a look through that and seems I'm having many issues with xamp/curl. Will look into it and see how it goes. Thanks for info

Comment: I had this same issue, I fixed this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323867/url-error-0-the-curl-request-was-retried-3-times-and-did-not-succeed/47232837#47232837