# How to send http2 request to APNS in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, push-notification, http2

In our application using PHP 5.6 version. In this version is not enable HTTP2 protocol. So we can't able to send a push notification to the APNS. Suddenly we can't able to upgrade the PHP versions.

How can I enable HTTP2 protocol and send a notification to APNS.

We tried lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to rebuild PHP curl extension with libcurl which has HTTP/2 support enabled (`--with-nghttp2`). After that, 
 You can use [duccio/apns-php](https://packagist.org/packages/duccio/apns-php) [v2.0.0-alpha](https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha) library to send HTTP/2 request to [APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html).

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34609756) for details.